# Reference something in the select clause SQL

Tags: sql, select, clause

I was wondering if you can reference something in the where clause like:

```
select
sum([some calculation]) as x,
sum([some other calculation]) as y,
x/y as z
from 
[rest of the sql...]
```

Many Thanks

K

Comment: If you mean can the `WHERE` clause access the results x, y, and z then the answer is no.  They can be accessed in a `HAVING` clause though, which is run on the results of the query before it is returned.  As such it is less efficient and so should only be used if there is no better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot used the alias that was generated on the same level on the `SELECT` statement.

Here are the possible ways to accomplish.

Using the original formula:

```
select sum([some calculation]) as x,
       sum([some other calculation]) as y,
       sum([some calculation]) / sum([some other calculation]) as z
from    tableName
```

or by using subquery:

```
SELECT  x,
        y,
        x/y z
FROM 
(
   select sum([some calculation]) as x,
          sum([some other calculation]) as y
   from   tableName
) s
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a shame... I was hoping I could do it the lazy way

Comment: hehe just choose the best one that fits for you `:D`

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard does not support this. You have to write:

```
select
sum([some calculation]) as x,
sum([some other calculation]) as y,
sum([some calculation])/sum([some other calculation]) as z
from 
[rest of the sql...]
```

There may be some RDBMS out there that support your syntax, though.

Comment: there is none that support `:)`